# Parsing an array as columns in Dataflow in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a incoming json input as below. I am able to parse almost all the data and load into my db. But its the custom_checks section, that I need some assistance please on how to parse them properly. Currently, i have them all being loaded into a single column (in the db) as a string. This is to be done inside the dataflow (maybe via a derived column)

Here is the primary issue.

I can expect to receive 1 or 2 or 4 different custom_types and their respective values. Only one value will be with one custom_type
The order can be different.
ex: 998 (translates to region) can come second
4466 (translates to vehicle) can come first
All expected custom_types are
998 - Region
4466 - Vehicle
3356 - Mobile
2311 - SubRegion.

My expectation is, to have four columns in the DB so i can map each of these elements from the array to their respective column in sql db. How can this be achievable since there is randomness in this. I tried using the Flatten activity in the dataflow, but not sure how to map the individual custom_types to field as they are not in set order.

So eventually, in the sql db, for row with ID = 2A457fytg79, the column Region will have a value of East and column Vehicle will have a value of Totota and the columns Mobile and Subregion will be blank.

The incoming json is as below.

```json
{
    "previous": "https://previouslink.com",
    "results": [
        {
            "TM_Sent": false,
            "appt_check": false,
            "custom_checks": [
                {
                    "custom_type": 998,
                    "Type_value": "East"
                },
                {
                    "custom_type": 4466,
                    "Type_value": "Toyota"
                }
            ],
            "deleted_flag": false,
            "id": "2A457fytg79",
            "tele_url": null
        }
    ],
    "next": "https://nextlink.com"
}a
```

I tried using locate function or the find function, but not sure how to capture the type_value accordingly as the custom_type&type_value set can be random as in, the region can come first or the second or the third.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you need to use pivot transformation to convert flattened rows to column.

I took Similar source as data you have provided.

[image]

1. Flatten the **results** array using Flatten transformation as below:
   [image]
2. Now Flatten the **custom_checks** array using another Flatten transformation and also add columns from previous flatten transformation as below:
   [image]
   It will give you data something like this:
   [image]
3. Now take Pivot transformation to convert rows into column with below settings:
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   It will give you data something like this:
   [image]
4. In this data preview click on **Map drifted**
   [image]
   It will create derive column which will map this drifted column you just rename it as you mentioned `998 - Region, 4466 - Vehicle, 3356 - Mobile, 2311 - SubRegion`.
   [image]
5. Use select transformation to select the required columns.
   [image]

**Final Output:**

[image]